# Laravel - Views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm in the process of transitioning from using CodeIgniter to something a but more fun like Laravel. I'm also learning to use the Blade templating engine with Laravel. I used to be able to do this in CI to render a view as HTML:

```
$this->load->view('about', $data, TRUE);
```

After reading Laravels documentation on views and some articles on StackOverflow, I can't figure out how to accomplish this with Laravel/Blade.

Comment: Did you happen to see this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My CodeIgniter skills are a bit rusted. But if I remember correctly your line of code renders the corresponding view and returns it as a string.

The equivalent with Laravel would be this:

```
$string = View::make('about', $data)->render();
```

Remember to import the View facade.

Or alternatively you can use the helper function:

```
$string = view('about', $data)->render();
```